# Rails will not run this PostgreSQL migration, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, type-conversion

I have this as a migration :

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table enterprise_members
    alter column sso_id
    type string using cast(sso_id as string)
  })
end
```

Where I am simply trying to convert an integer into a string. But when run, it returns :

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
: 
        alter table enterprise_members
        alter column sso_id
        type string using cast(sso_id as string)
```

Is it because I'm trying to cast it? How do I fix this?

Comment: Varchar, char, text are database typesm "string" is not. Character data types can be found on the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `string` when you are using Rails but if you choose to go the manual way, as you did in your snippet, you have to stick in your [DBMS' datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype.html)

Which brings up another point: try to be DB-agnostic when you can!

Comment: Evidently I couldn't cast the other way and I had to write it manual.